# Keep up with a Facebook Page [bucket test[

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

**CONTEXT:**

A new Facebook feature prompts you to like the creators(owner) page for a given piece of content you share or like.

I have encountered the feature in 2 different occasions:

A - When sharing an aticle from [slate. com] I was prompted to like the [facebook page of slate .com] - screenshot here:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SydwT.png]

B - When sharing a youtube music video i was prompted to like the page of the band in that music video (even though the youtube channel that owned that content was the channel of the record company that distributes multiple music bands)

**MY QUESTION:**
What do you need to have set-up on the page/site in order to have Facebook recognize the link between your website and your facebook page?

I've added my admin_id and the page's app_id to the  on my site:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="1040395049" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="151466116651" />
```

It's kind of hard to test because this feature being bucket tested appears intermittently, if you have any thought of how i might test that I'm ready to take advantage the feature that'd be very helpful.

Comment: What documentation are you looking at while trying to implement this feature?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ step 2 about the tags. basically i assume i need to claim he domain - so i figured adding the app_id would do it. HOWEVER i'm only guessing that this is all that needs to be done in order to access that "Keep up with ..." feature